# Delphi does not generate any exe file

Tags: delphi, compilation, exe

I have installed Delphi 2010 and tried to create a new project clearly.
but when i compile my project, delphi does not generate any exe file.

also when i try to run application i get this error:
**Could not find program, "C:\test\Project1.exe"**

**note**: i haven't changed any configuration or settings of Delphi or project.
everything is as it's default

Comment: And the mentioned path c:\test\ exists ?

Comment: Sounds like UAC or anti-virus or something like that.

Comment: I've had similar problem with Win7 and D2009 when I tried to create output files wherever on my system drive. Delphi doesn't write the compiled result until I open Delphi as administrator.

Comment: @daemon_x: c:\test\ exist and i tried to run it as administrator but problem did not solved

Comment: @David Heffernan: I also disabled antivirus.

Comment: Can you post the the source code to the DPK/DPR of the project.   This is common if you have built a library and set the host application to "C:\test\Project1.exe"

Comment: Like robert suggests, please post the DPK/DPR source or a simple screenshot of your Project Options and Run Parameters.

Comment: @Robert, Paul: I added the DPR source  all the options of project are default, no host or any other parameter has been set

Comment: IN this case I think you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was about getting absolute path because i'd changed `ProgramFilesPath` and `ProgramFilesDir` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` to `D:` without leading backslash.

I changed it to `D:\` and the problem was solved now

thank you all

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Vista or later, this could be because of UAC settings.  Try setting the project output folder in Project->Options to something a limited account would have access to, such as somewhere under `My Documents\RAD Studio\Projects`.

Comment: @Omid - when you run Build for your project, are you getting an error message? If Delphi can't create the file, you will get an error message. This sometimes happens with an 'orphan process' - process still running from same exe that didn't close down properly. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Run [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), search for any open handles to `C:\test\Project1.exe` using [Find, Find handle or dll](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm).

That will tell you what is locking your .exe.

---

Edit 20221221 because of [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot):

- [[Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20110509141349/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)/[Archive](https://archive.vn/2014.05.28-180412/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)] [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) redirects to [[Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20221221095537/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)/[Archive](https://archive.ph/2022.12.21-095546/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)] [Process Explorer - Sysinternals | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
- [[Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20110610104309/http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm)/[Archive](https://archive.vn/2011.06.10-104309/http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm)] [Know which process has locked a file](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm) has died and moved to[[Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20221221095728/https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-process-locked-file-openfiles-utility/)/[Archive](https://archive.ph/2022.12.21-104723/https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-process-locked-file-openfiles-utility/)] [How to Identify the Process that has Locked a File in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-process-locked-file-openfiles-utility/) and added solutions based on resmon.exe (built-in), handle.exe (SysInternals), [OpenFiles.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openfiles) (built-in, but requires a global flag to be enabled which for enabling requires a reboot).
- [[Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20221221150432/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)/[Archive](https://archive.ph/2022.12.21-150354/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)] [Handle - Sysinternals | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)

Comment: There is another tool from Mark R, called "handle". It also shows all open handles. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

Comment: Note though that `handle.exe` does find less handles than `procexp.exe` (even when running as `LocalSystem`. It for instance misses handles from the patterns `\BCD` and `\cmd.exe`, see https://twitter.com/jpluimers/status/1605603130636324865 (hopefully Russinovich chimes in).

Oh: I will edit my answer with current links as parts have died.

Comment: Also note that `resmon.exe` (even when ran as `LocalSystem`) has the same problems as `handle.exe`: https://twitter.com/jpluimers/status/1605628036128309248

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem on Windows 7.
Installing it as administrator solved the problem IIRC.

If that doesn't work then make sure you run it as administrator.

You are running it on XP though, so unless you've installed it as a non-administrator, or run it as a non-administrator this shouldn't be happening.
*Note that if you're in a domain, it's possible that you're not local admin on your XP machine.*

Comment: Even a non-admin user should be able to write to his own Documents folder.

Comment: Yep, but I've had Delphi misbehave if not **installed** using an admin account.

Comment: @Warren P, this was a long time ago, I'm not completly sure of the details, just know that it didn't work properly, sorry that I'm unable to give more details.